# Success or successes? Which is correct?

Tags: questions

I am making a greeting card for our Client's Company Anniversary, which of these two is correct?

"May you achieve greater success in years to come."
or
"May you achieve greater successes in years to come."?

And is it safe to add "even" or "much" before the word "greater"?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd use "even greater". Not using it could be ambiguous and understood as awareness that they haven't achieved much of a success so far.

Comment: Or you could drop the-er and say "May you achieve great success in years to come." Of course you would not use the adverbs then.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is safe to add "even" or "much" before, they are adverbs and provide emphasis.

As far as ***success*** vs ***successes*** this just depends on what you want to say.

Success can be defined as:

- the fact of getting or achieving wealth, respect, or fame
- the correct or desired result of an attempt

So you can either use ***success*** which would imply the first definition. "May you achieve a greater overall sense of accomplshment/wealth/fame etc."

or with the ***successes*** which would imply the second definition: "May you achieve a series of desired outcomes from the many things you attempt in life"

So if you're wishing an overall sense of success you'd leave off the plural. If you want to emphasize success with individual events or tasks they may undertake then use the plural.

Comment: Isn't successes plural? Eg. *The success of the battle won the fort.* *The successes of the battle won the fort.* The second one implies that there was more than 1 success that led to the victory (perhaps through a combination of chance happenings).

Comment: @Tucker Yes, of course. Perhaps I should clarify, but I meant that "successes" implies the second definition, but with multiples. You won't very well achieve fame and wealth multiple times, that is sort of an all-encompassing definition. The second definition is reserved for individual instances, in which plurality applies there best.

Comment: Ah! I see what you mean. Yes, you are correct. That's interesting, though. Now to look for a all-encompassing word...